# Error while trying to install openstack using devstack

Tags: openstack

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install openstack using devstack. I've set the host to be `10.112.19.50` and have disabled `v2.0` of keystone, so it is using v3.

error is :

> Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating
>   the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
>   2016-05-13 10:12:02.129 | Could not determine a suitable URL for the
>   plugin

```
2016-05-13 10:10:54.598 | 2016-05-13 15:40:54.598 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created domain default
2016-05-13 10:11:09.602 | 2016-05-13 15:41:09.601 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created project admin
2016-05-13 10:11:15.610 | 2016-05-13 15:41:15.610 9066 DEBUG passlib.registry [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] registered 'sha512_crypt' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.sha2_crypt.sha512_crypt'> register_crypt_handler /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/passlib/registry.py:284
2016-05-13 10:11:15.870 | 2016-05-13 15:41:15.870 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created user admin
2016-05-13 10:11:18.602 | 2016-05-13 15:41:18.602 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created Role admin
2016-05-13 10:11:18.634 | 2016-05-13 15:41:18.633 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Granted admin on admin to user admin.
2016-05-13 10:11:24.644 | 2016-05-13 15:41:24.644 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created Region RegionOne
2016-05-13 10:11:36.641 | 2016-05-13 15:41:36.641 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created admin endpoint http://10.112.19.50:35357/v3
2016-05-13 10:11:48.709 | 2016-05-13 15:41:48.709 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created internal endpoint http://10.112.19.50:5000/v3
2016-05-13 10:12:00.749 | 2016-05-13 15:42:00.748 9066 INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-54bc60f5-16d7-44f5-b478-b5eaaf074006 - - - - -] Created public endpoint http://10.112.19.50:5000/v3
2016-05-13 10:12:00.814 | +./stack.sh:main:1007                      is_service_enabled tls-proxy
2016-05-13 10:12:00.834 | +functions-common:is_service_enabled:2055  return 1
2016-05-13 10:12:00.838 | +./stack.sh:main:1016 cat
2016-05-13 10:12:00.854 | +./stack.sh:main:1031 source /home/space/devstack/userrc_early
2016-05-13 10:12:00.859 | ++userrc_early:source:4 export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
2016-05-13 10:12:00.864 | ++userrc_early:source:4 OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
2016-05-13 10:12:00.869 | ++userrc_early:source:5 export OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.112.19.50:5000
2016-05-13 10:12:00.873 | ++userrc_early:source:5 OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.112.19.50:5000
2016-05-13 10:12:00.878 | ++userrc_early:source:6 export OS_USERNAME=admin
2016-05-13 10:12:00.882 | ++userrc_early:source:6 OS_USERNAME=admin
2016-05-13 10:12:00.886 | ++userrc_early:source:7 export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
2016-05-13 10:12:00.890 | ++userrc_early:source:7 OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
2016-05-13 10:12:00.894 | ++userrc_early:source:8 export OS_PASSWORD=nomoresecret
2016-05-13 10:12:00.898 | ++userrc_early:source:8 OS_PASSWORD=nomoresecret
2016-05-13 10:12:00.903 | ++userrc_early:source:9 export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
2016-05-13 10:12:00.908 | ++userrc_early:source:9 OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
2016-05-13 10:12:00.913 | ++userrc_early:source:10 export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
2016-05-13 10:12:00.918 | ++userrc_early:source:10 OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
2016-05-13 10:12:00.922 | ++userrc_early:source:11 export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
2016-05-13 10:12:00.926 | ++userrc_early:source:11 OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
2016-05-13 10:12:00.929 | +./stack.sh:main:1033 create_keystone_accounts
2016-05-13 10:12:00.932 | +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:372  local admin_tenant
2016-05-13 10:12:00.937 | ++lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:373  openstack project show admin -f value -c id
2016-05-13 10:12:02.129 | Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
2016-05-13 10:12:02.129 | Could not determine a suitable URL for the plugin
2016-05-13 10:12:02.159 | +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:373  admin_tenant=
2016-05-13 10:12:02.163 | +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:1 exit_trap
2016-05-13 10:12:02.168 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:474 local r=1
2016-05-13 10:12:02.173 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:475 jobs -p
2016-05-13 10:12:02.178 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:475 jobs=
2016-05-13 10:12:02.183 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:478 [[ -n '' ]]
2016-05-13 10:12:02.187 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:484 kill_spinner
2016-05-13 10:12:02.191 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:370 '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-05-13 10:12:02.195 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:486 [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-05-13 10:12:02.200 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487 echo 'Error on exit'
2016-05-13 10:12:02.200 | Error on exit
2016-05-13 10:12:02.205 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488 generate-subunit 1463133935 387 fail
2016-05-13 10:12:02.468 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:489 [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2016-05-13 10:12:02.474 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:492 /home/space/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2016-05-13 10:12:03.152 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:498 exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you.
I think that is related to your old version authentication.
Just do the following steps
1.close your old terminal and open a new one (maybe you did 'source admin-openrc.sh' to get the authentication)
2../unstack.sh
3../clean.sh
4.sudo rm -rf /opt/stack
5../stack.sh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you.then i use the sample local.conf,then it work 
https://github.com/shake/devstack/blob/gh-pages/local.conf-sample-mitaka

In the end I found when I enable "gnocchi" in local.conf,it will "Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL"

Comment: hey have you successfully installed gnocchi? can I get some tips on configurations? I did tried to install gnocchi via devstack but got this error https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/108789/403-forbidden-gnocchi-api/ can you help me with this..regards:)